# Dynamic or Conditional display of Jenkins job's parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am trying to use following jenkins job to generate Active Choices user selectable params for a job.

my ask is to show/hide textbox when heartbeat_consumer checkbox is selected/unselected. I would also like to store the value of user input in `heartbeat_consumer_parms`, which can be accessed thru `env.heartbeat_consumer_parms`. I plan to use this value in downstream jobs.

```
pipeline {
    agent any
        stages {
            stage('Parameters'){
                steps {
                    script {
                    properties([
                            parameters([
                            text(
                                defaultValue: '''''', 
                                name: 'application_servers',
                                description: 'Please provide semicolon delimited (;) application server list ', 
                            ),
                            [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
                                choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
                                description: 'Select Services',
                                name: 'application_services_list', 
                                referencedParameters: 'application_servers', 
                                script: 
                                    [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                    fallbackScript: [
                                            classpath: [], 
                                            sandbox: false, 
                                            script: "return['']"
                                            ], 
                                    script: [
                                            classpath: [], 
                                            sandbox: false, 
                                            script: '''
                                            if (application_servers.length() > 0){
                                                return["heartbeat_consumer", "surgeon_cloud_login", "system_configuration"]
                                            }
                                            '''
                                        ] 
                                ]
                            ]
                            ])
                        ])
                    if (application_services_list.contains('heartbeat_consumer')){
                            text(
                            defaultValue: '''''', 
                            name: 'heartbeat_consumer_parms',
                            description: 'Please provide heartbeatconsumer job parms ', 
                            )
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

with current implmentation I am not seeing that textbox `heartbeat_consumer_parms` is being displayed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this worked for me,

```
 pipeline {
    agent any
        stages {
            stage('Parameters'){
                steps {
                    script {
                    properties([
                            parameters([
                            text(
                                defaultValue: '''''', 
                                name: 'application_servers',
                                description: 'Please provide semicolon delimited (;) application server list ', 
                            ),
                                [$class: 'CascadeChoiceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
                                    description: 'Select Services',
                                    name: 'application_services_list', 
                                    referencedParameters: 'application_servers', 
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: "return['']"
                                                ], 
                                        script: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: '''
                                                if (application_servers.length() > 0){
                                                    return["heartbeat_consumer", "surgeon_cloud_login", "system_configuration"]
                                                }
                                                '''
                                            ] 
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
                                    description: 'enter job params',
                                    name: 'hb_job_params', 
                                    referencedParameters: 'application_services_list', 
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: "return['']"
                                                ], 
                                        script: [
                                                classpath: [], 
                                                sandbox: false, 
                                                script: '''
                                                if (application_services_list.contains('heartbeat_consumer')){
                                                    return """<textarea name=\"value\" rows=\"5\" class=\"setting-input   \"></textarea>"""

                                                }
                                                '''
                                            ] 
                                    ],
                                omitValueField: true
                                ],
                            ])
                        ])
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image: build params entered in hb_job_params are present in 'Build Parameters']

I used, `DynamicReferenceParameter` for using HTML generated `textarea` however accessing entered `textarea` values was tricky. after a bit of researching I found that,

**The trick for formatting a text input box is to format the HTML in a way that reflects the HTML Jenkins uses to display parameters in a job submission form. The easiest way to do this is to review the HTML Jenkins uses to display an existing String parameter.**

src: https://github.com/biouno/uno-choice-plugin/wiki/Using-Uno-Choice-for-Dynamic-Input-Text-Box-Defaults

Comment: and how are you referencing these parameters from your pipeline script? are the part of the params object/collection?

Answer (score 0):

Pipeline script for your scenario:

```yaml
properties([
                            parameters([
                                [$class: 'ChoiceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'PT_CHECKBOX', 
                                    description: 'Select the Application Service from the Dropdown List', 
                                    filterLength: 1, 
                                    filterable: false, 
                                    name: 'application_services_list', 
                                    script: [
                                        $class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        fallbackScript: [
                                            classpath: [], 
                                            sandbox: false, 
                                            script: 
                                                "return['Could not get the services list']"
                                        ], 
                                        script: [
                                            classpath: [], 
                                            sandbox: false, 
                                            script: 
                                                "return['heartbeat_consumer', 'surgeon_cloud_login', 'system_configuration']"
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ],
                                [$class: 'DynamicReferenceParameter', 
                                    choiceType: 'ET_FORMATTED_HTML', 
                                    description: 'SAdd params', 
                                    name: 'heartbeat_consumer_parms',
                                    omitValueField: 'true',
                                    referencedParameters: 'application_services_list', 
                                    script: 
                                        [$class: 'GroovyScript', 
                                        script: 'return["Could not get Information"]', 
                                        script: [
                                            script: '''
                                                    
                                                    if (application_services_list.equals("heartbeat_consumer")){
                                                    inputBox="<input type ='text' id = 'myText' name='value' >"
                                                    return inputBox
                                                    }
                                                    
                                                    '''
                                                ]
                                        ]
                                ]
                            ])
                        ])
pipeline {
    environment {
         vari = ""
  }
  agent any
  stages {
      stage ("Example") {
        steps {
         script{

          echo "${params.application_services_list}"
          echo '\n'
          echo "${params.heartbeat_consumer_parms}"
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please find the screenshot of the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Output of pipeline after build:

[image]

[image]

Comment: great, can you also let me know about how can I access the value entered inside inputBox in some variable, which can be used in build step

Comment: @Vaibhav I have modified the pipeline script according to your ask. Hope this might help you.

Comment: can this be a multi-line text box?